# Unresolved reference: isIgnoringBatteryOptimization

Tags: android, kotlin, android-powermanager

I'm trying to check if my application is ignoring the battery optimization, I have to force users allow the application in that, I don't wanna to be banned from PlayStore, I saw some references saying that the permission is dangerous. Then, until now, I'm trying this "solution" from code below. I saw the reference in documentation here [isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager#isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(java.lang.String)), but in my Android studio it gives me the follow error:

> `Unresolved reference: isIgnoringBatteryOptimization`

The code I wrote:

```
import android.os.PowerManager

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        openPowerSettings(this)    
    }

    private fun openPowerSettings(context: Context) {
        if(PowerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimization(context.packageName)){
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.action = Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get `PowerManager` system-level service using `Context#getSystemService(String)`

```kotlin
 private fun openPowerSettings(context: Context) {
        val powerManager = getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        if (powerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(context.packageName)) {
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.action = Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```

Comment: tks Arpan for help me ^^